# HTML Right edge overflows on android

Tags: html, css

I'm currently developing a Sudoku solving app in HTML/JS. The programming part is more or less finalized, but with little or no experience in web design, the layout of my app seems to be screwing up.

Here are my CSS styles:

```
body{
    background-color: #faf8ef;
}

.container{
    width: 436px;
    margin:0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.heading_container{
    width: 436px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.heading_title{
    width: 436px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.heading_info{
    width: 436px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-grid{
    width: 436px;
    background-color: #bbada0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 3px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    clear:both;
}

.big-grid{
}

.small-grid{
    width:43px;
    height:43px;
    border:1px gray;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="heading_container">
        <div class="heading_title"><span style="font-family:verdana; font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold">Sudoku Solver</span></div>
    </div>

    <table class="main-grid" cellspacing="2px">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is what happens when I run it on my desktop and on my android mobile device:

[image: Desktop]
[image: Android]

It runs fine on the desktop, but the right edge of the grid seems to get cut off when I run it on my Android. I suspect that this is an overflowing issue, and have tried changing the widths from 100% to a constant pixel width, but it does not seem to work. Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. Do feel free to nitpick and suggest any improvements for my code. I'm still new so I would like to learn more about what is the "best" way to get things done!

Answer (score 0):

Body has a margin default by the browser.Try resetting it by specifying

```
body { margin: 0px; }
```

If it still doesnt work remove the margin:0px auto property and set margins